# Is it possible to trigger animations only when button is clicked without using javascript using css or scss

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I want to trigger animations only when a button is clicked without JavaScript using css or scss.

I tried to use :active, but the animation is also triggered even after the page is loaded.

I think JavaScript may solve this problem but I want to know if it is possible to solve it only using css or scss.

```css
#clickMe:active{
  animation: rotateAnimation 2s linear;
}

@keyframes rotateAnimation {
  from{transform:rotate(0deg);}
  to{transform:rotate(365deg);}
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to achieve a whole rotation with :active selector because button is only active for a short time after you clicked on it.

It makes more sense to use JavaScript in this case because it will trigger animation for an click event, not :active state of an element.

But if you really want to achieve this only by CSS, you can use an input checkbox. Style it like a button first. Then, set CSS animation for it with using :checked selector. Again, it's better to pick a method that makes sense because keeping code readable is crucial as a developer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:focus` to achieve the same. Try out this :

```css
#clickMe:focus{
  animation: rotateAnimation 2s linear;
}

@keyframes rotateAnimation {
  from{transform:rotate(0deg);}
  to{transform:rotate(365deg);}
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
</body>
```

Comment: The animation won't be triggered when it's focused already like another click after the first click. I think he wants to trigger animation every time a button is clicked.

Comment: @KoutaNakano That'd not be possible without javascript. However, we don't know what's really gonna happen on webpage after the click, so let's leave it to him/her :)